# Need Help Adding an Integer Array to an Array List in Processing

Tags: java, javascript, arrays, arraylist, processing

Ok... So I am in the middle of a project, and I've hit a bit of a wall. If anyone could please explain how to add an integer array to an ArrayList of integer Arrays, I would greatly appreciate it. This is in processing, the javascript version more specifically. I have tested and everything works right up to 'symbols.get(i).add(tempArray). If I print tempArray right before that line it gives me '6 10 16 10 16 20', as it should. And no, it's not just the println(symbols) statement, I also tried just 'println("blah");'and that did not show up in the output, so something is going awry at the .get line.

```
size(850,250);
String[] myList = new String[100];
ArrayList<Integer[]> symbols = new ArrayList<Integer[]>();
int[] tempArray = new int[];

String numbers = ("6,10,16,10,16,20\n1,25,21,13,3,15\n6,5,20,6,21,20");

myList = (split(numbers, "\n"));
int j = myList.length();
for(int i = 0; i<j; i++)
{
tempArray = int(split(myList[i], ','));
symbols.get(i).add(tempArray);
}
println(symbols);
```

... I have also tried the following in place of 'symbols.get(i).add(tempArray);'

```
for(int a = 0; a < tempArray.length(); a++)
{
symbols.get(i[a]) = tempArray[a];
}
println(symbols);
```

... I have also tried

```
for(int a = 0; a < tempArray.length(); a++)
{
symbols.get(i) = tempArray[a];
}
println(symbols);
```

... and

```
for(int a = 0; a < tempArray.length(); a++)
{
symbols[i][a] = tempArray[a];
}
println(symbols);
```

I'm out of guesses and tries, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you mean println(symbols) is not executed and without any exception?

Answer (score 1):

First get the Array of integer by using the get method on the ArrayList, then add [index] to specify what to add at which index of the returned Array.

```
symbols.get(i)[a] = tempArray[a];
```

Answer (score 1):

There are some mistakes. The key one is that you can't add `int[]` to the list expecting `Integer[]`. Here, see the comments on the code:

```
void setup()
{
  size(850, 250);

  String[] myList = new String[100];
  ArrayList<Integer[]> symbols = new ArrayList<Integer[]>();

  // you can't init an array without a inintial dimension 
  //int[] tempArray = new int[];
  int[] tempArray;

  String numbers = ("6,10,16,10,16,20\n1,25,21,13,3,15\n6,5,20,6,21,20");

  myList = (split(numbers, "\n"));

  //length is not a method... no parenthesis here
  //int j = myList.length();
  int j = myList.length;
  for (int i = 0; i<j; i++)
  {
    tempArray = int(split(myList[i], ','));

    // you cant add an int[] to an Integer[] arrayList
    // you gotta either change the arraylist type or convert the ints to Integers
    // also just use .add(). not get().add() it's a one dimension list

    symbols.add(parseArray(tempArray));
      println(symbols.get(i) );
      println("--");
  }

}

//convenience function..  
Integer[] parseArray(int[] a) {
  Integer[] b = new Integer[a.length];

  for (int i = 0; i<a.length; i++) {
    b[i] = Integer.valueOf(a[i]);
  }

  return b;
}
```

and the other way...

```
void setup()
{
  size(850, 250);

  String[] myList = new String[100];
  ArrayList<int[]> symbols = new ArrayList<int[]>();

  // you can't init an array without a inintial dimension 
  //int[] tempArray = new int[];
  int[] tempArray;

  String numbers = ("6,10,16,10,16,20\n1,25,21,13,3,15\n6,5,20,6,21,20");

  myList = (split(numbers, "\n"));

  //length is not a method... no parenthesis here
  //int j = myList.length();
  int j = myList.length;
  for (int i = 0; i<j; i++)
  {
    tempArray = int(split(myList[i], ','));
    symbols.add(tempArray);
      println(symbols.get(i) );
      println("--");
  }

}
```